# Picturefill in IE11 with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vue.js, picturefill

In IE11 the [Picturefill](https://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/) library doesn't work with Vue.js. I get the following warning:

`[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <picture> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

I can remove the warning by using `Vue.config.ignoredElements = ['picture']` but that doesn't seem to fix the issue. I think under the hood Vue.js is doing things with the picture tag because it doesn't get recognized by IE11 and therefor Vue.js thinks its a custom tag?

Please let me know how to fix this problem! Thanks

Comment: Same works in other browsers: chrome/firefox?

Comment: It works in other browsers, just not IE11 and probably older versions of it. Because it doesn't recognize the picture element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IE11, You have to make a picturefill function call after picture tags are loaded in DOM. It will dynamically add the src attribute to img tag.

```
//For IE 11 Fix
    if(typeof picturefill === "function") {
      picturefill();
    }
```